# undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating instagram app from https://medium.com/luanotes/build-instagram-by-ruby-on-rails-part-2-d70b44f5c7e6.

Under this topic: Add a form to create a new Post in Homepage

I am getting this error :
`undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`

my index view file

```
<%= form_for Post.new do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :user_id,nil, value: current_user.id, class:'d-none'%>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="text-center">
    <%= f.submit 'Create Post', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        Post.create(post_params)

        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:description, :image, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Routes are:

```
  root to: 'home#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  resources :posts, only: [:new, :create]
```

Comment: Does your post `belongs_to :user`?

Comment: @hashrocket Yes

Comment: Then you have to assign a user to the post when creating the post.

Comment: @hashrocket My user have `has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: In your post create action, you have to assign a user to the post.

Comment: @hashrocket How can I do that?

Comment: What are you using for authentication? Devise?

Comment: @hashrocket Yes Devise

Comment: What are you using for authentication? Devise?

Comment: @hashrocket Yes I am using Devise  for authentication.

Comment: @hashrocket I have inserted the form in `views/home/index.html.erb`. Is this correct?

Comment: @hashrocket But in this https://medium.com/luanotes/build-instagram-by-ruby-on-rails-part-2-d70b44f5c7e6 it is written to `Add a form to create a new Post in Homepage `